# Angular2 Reactive Form : Validate fields inside *ngIf

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-material2, angular-reactive-forms

I have a form with `md-select` and `md-radio-button` fields. The options under radio button will be displayed according to the option selected in md-select. Please visit the [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/TL7hgfkRrquVVlCM4pN8?p=preview).

You can see I have created the form with the sub-organism radio-button field to be required. It works on the first load. But if we select any sub radio button option and then change the organism select box, the form is still valid, without having a valid sub-orgranism value. I need the form to be invalid, if the sub radio button is not checked. Please help.

Question 2 : Also in the plunk, please uncomment the following lines after line 47 in app.component.ts so that there will be a default value for the fields. The sub organism radio buttons will be displayed, but the selectbox will be blank. There is the selected value and thats the reason why sub organism fields are displayed. Not sure why the option is not selected for organisms md-select.

Comment: For question 2, the plunk shows using FormControl with NgModel. They are mutually exclusive, so only one should be used. Also note that md-select compares values by *object reference* not object value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `change` event to `md-select` so that if the selection changes, and the form was validated, you can reset the value of `selected.sub_organism_id` to `null`. That will make the form invalid.

Code snippets:

html:

```
<md-select [formControl]="form.controls['organism']" 
           style="width:100%;" 
           [(ngModel)]="selected.organism_id" 
           (change)="resetForm($event)">
  <md-option *ngFor="let organism_id of getIds()" [value]="organism_id">
    {{ organisms[organism_id].name }}
  </md-option>
</md-select>
```

ts:

```
resetForm(org){
  if(this.form.valid){
    this.selected.sub_organism_id = null;
  };  
}
```

[Edited Plunk](https://plnkr.co/edit/wsYASLW3nWaN3jknUTtk?p=preview)

**Update:**

Like @WillHowell said in his comment, "md-select compares values by object reference not object value" which is true. I modified your data to an array-object relation, and md-select default value worked [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/rniE7BSRKDwEceatQffZ?p=preview).

Comment: Thanks for your reply and I got the first part working. The last plunker link is the same one, with key:object relation. It would be great if you can paste a working one as I couldn't make question2 working.

Comment: Sorry about that, I have added the correct link for second part. Let me know what you think